# Issue with Javascript if statement that calls for different alert messages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help putting multiple if statements into my function. I need it to check to make sure their is an input in input1 (first name) input2 (lastname) input6 (email) and input8(message box). I need it to then pop up an alert if one field is empty and state what field that is. I coded it up earlier with seperate functions and then called the functions on submit but then it pops up all the alerts pending that the field is empty. I would rather have it pop up only one alert then return false to exit the script so it doesnt spam you with 4 alerts and then cancel the script. Thanks!

Update: I have it working for the first three fields i need (First/Lastname and email) I just need to add an alert for the message box, but it seems .length is not working for the message box... any ideas? I tried doing the same as the others, but it breaks the code and does nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Contact Us</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="main_body" >


    <div id="form_container">


        <form id="form_1121982" class="appnitro" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="form_description">

            <p></p>
        </div>                      
        <h1 align="center">Contact Us</h1>  

            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Name </label>
        <span>
            <input id="input1" name= "input1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value=""/>
            <label>First</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="input2" name= "input2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
            <label>Last</label>
        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Phone </label>
        <span>
            <input id="input3" name="input3" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
            <label for="input3">(###)</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="input4" name="input4" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
            <label for="input4">###</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="input5" name="input5" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
            <label for="input5">####</label>
        </span>

        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="input6">Email </label>
        <div>
            <input id="input6" name="input6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="input7">Upload a File </label>
        <div>
            <input id="input7" name="input7" class="element file" type="file"/> 
        </div>  
        </li>       <li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="input8">Paragraph </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="input9" name="input8" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1121982" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction1();" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">

        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

```
function myFunction1() 
 {
     var field1 = document.getElementById("input1").value.trim(); //checks length of first name
     var field2 = document.getElementById("input2").value.trim(); //checks length of first name
     var field6 = document.getElementById("input6").value.trim(); //checks length of first name

        if ( field1.length == 0 )
     {
        alert("Please Fill In Your First Name");
        return false;
     } 



        else if ( field2.length == 0 )
     {
        alert("Please Fill In Your Last Name");
        return false;
     } 

        else if( field6.length == 0 )
        {
        alert("Please Fill in Your Email");
        return false;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the return within your if statements.

```
if (field1.length == 0) {
    alert("Please Fill In Your First Name");
    return false;
}
```

---

To answer the second part of your question, though you haven't supplied the javascript on how you're trying to get the textarea.

Firstly, your naming convention isn't great. You should use something that is meaningful so you don't make mistakes which I think you have done here.

```
<textarea id="input9" name="input8" class="element textarea medium"></textarea>
```

Your textarea has `id=input9` with `name=input8`. Going by how you were doing this originally, it should be `id=input8`?

For your fields, use the naming of your labels. Eg `id=Firstname`, `id=Email` etc.

Comment: Thanks! That got it to cancel out idk why I had it outside on that. I have another question ill update it above.

Comment: @AndrewRibicki If it's a totally different question, then you should make a separate post instead of editing the current question.

Comment: @4castle It is basically the same question so I just added it on and left the previous question

Comment: Thanks! I looked over that. I will rename them, i pulled part of this from some previous code i had and just did not change it over yet! Thanks again for the help!